# Вопрос по добавлению нового параметра GET в термин таксономии ЧПУ Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, get, ссылки, чпу

Подскажите,кто работал с wordpress. Как добавить новый параметр GET в ЧПУ на страницы терминов определенной таксономии. Чтоб ссылка была вида site.com/taxonomy/term/новый_параметр/, при этом не нарушая пагинацию на странице.

Comment: Насколько я понял вопрос, вам нужно вот это: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: можно подробней? Как сделать в моем случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, ваш новый параметр называется brand. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно преобразовать ссылки вида

```
site.com/taxnomy/term/?brand=audi
```

в

```
site.com/taxonomy/term/audi
```

Тогда надо добавить такой код в functions.php вашей темы:

```
function rewrite_rules() {
    // Теги
    add_rewrite_tag( '%brand%', '([^&]+)', 'brand=' );

    // Правило перезаписи
    add_rewrite_rule( '^taxonomy/term/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?p=100&brand=$matches[1]', 'top' );

    // Скажем WP, что есть новые параметры запроса
    add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = 'brand';
        return $vars;
    } );
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rules' );
```

Сначала мы добавляем тег перезаписи, потому что без него правила перезаписи не работают.

Потом добавляем правило перезаписи, где p=100 - id поста, который будет отображать выполнение вашего запроса.

И, наконец, мы извещаем WP, что появился новый параметр запроса brand.