# Имеется Wordpress фильтр по get параметрам, как поменять GET параметры на постоянные ссылки?

Tags: wordpress

Фильтрую товары по параметрам полученных из GET вида
site.com/shop/?genre=techno&moth=october
Вопрос как реализовать такую строку

site.com/shop/techno/october/
Вместо гет параметров

Comment: Вот пример, думаю, то, что нужно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752655/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-get-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно использовать функцию `add_rewrite_rule` https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule